# Number prediction from 1 to 10 from javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code but when i run this code in console always giving me Congratulations.
Help me for solve this problem.

```
var val=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
console.log(val);
var Predict = Number(prompt("Prediction ?"));

for(var i=1 ; i <= 3; i++){
  if(Predict<val){console.log("Up")};
  if(Predict=val){console.log("Congratulations") };
  if(Predict>val){console.log("Down")}
}
```

Comment: You need == or === instead of = in the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equal operator assigns the right hand to the left hand and so the result is always true! To compare two values use double equals like this:

```
if (Predict==val){console.log("Congratulations") };
```